# Rounding floating variables in C to display upto only 2 digits of precision

Tags: c, floating-point-precision

I have a question - it may seem stupid to most, but i'm still a novice coder. 
How does one round a floating variable to display upto only 2 or 3 digits of precision ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the format specifier `%.2f` for 2 digits of precision. Similarly use `%.3f` for 3 digits. For future reference, here are the `printf` [format specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%.2f\n", 0.005); // prints 0.01
    printf("%.2f\n", 0.004); // prints 0.00
}
```

Comment: Auditing @Praetorian's answer you can also uses `%.*f`  for example `int precision = 3; printf("%.*f\n", precision, 0.00455);` it outputs:    `0.005`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I never know have a `*f`, thanks. :)

Comment: @herohuyongtao The `*` can be used in the field width specifier also, and in that case the argument is allowed to be negative too, which signifies the output should be left aligned.

Comment: @Praetorian Can you share a small example?

Comment: @herohuyongtao [Here you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d520bd13c9d6e31)

Comment: @Praetorian Note: the `0.005` is lucky.  Typically such values are not representable exactly as a double (in this case it is likely `0.005000000000000000104...` which displays a rounded to 2 digits value of "0.01").  Had the example been `0.015` with a hoped for rounded value of "0.02", the value passed would be `0.01499999999999999944...` and would have also displayed "0.01".  An example value of `0.006` would have less ambiguity.

Comment: Sippose if I have a=123.45678 , and I want to display only 123.456, so how can I do this?